Receiving "inf" error when running QGIS Zonal Statistics
I have been analyzing precipitation data from the NOAA (see here - https://water.noaa.gov/resources/downloads/precip/stageIV/) where I use QGIS to calculate the mean/median/min/max precipitation for the contiguous United States. Despite doing this on a monthly basis for a year now, whenever I have tried to run the data for July 2024 (https://water.noaa.gov/resources/downloads/precip/stageIV/2024/08/01/nws_precip_mtd_20240801_conus.tif) I get an "inf" output in the attribute table for mean and max values. This is the same error I receive on other files like the last 30 days file for August 1st and July 31st or the month to date file for July 31st that show essentially the same data.
What is this error and is it an issue with the underlying data in the raster file, or with my version of QGIS?

Works for me (screenshot), though your median value is way different to what I get.  Maybe provide more info about your zone data (I just googled for s_22mr22 and grabbed the first shapefile I found), project CRS and which raster band you selected in zonal stats.  Try also running fix geometries tool on your zones.

It doesn't seem to work though does it? We had a hurricane come through and you're only getting a mean/median value of ~6%... Lowest mean/median I've ever seen is in the 60%s even with super dry weather. I'm running on raster band 4 with the dissolved layer over the contiguous US as my input layer for zonal statistics. They changed the format/data on the NOAA website a few months ago and I'm essentially trying to see if the NOAA data has holes or not given these inf errors
